# How to get the current time in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to create a Google Form with 2 sections and I want to get the current time when the filler clicks at the NEXT button on section 1. The time should be displayed with the submitted answers later.

[image]

Is there any way to do that with Google Scripts?

Comment: I don't think so. Not with a Google Form.  Try writing your own html form or webapp.

Comment: Hey there, you can get the time when the whole form is submitted but you cannot do it seprately for each section. Just like @Cooper has mentioned, you might need to take a different approach on this. You can seperate the form into two - one for each section and in this way you are able to retrieve the time for each of them. Does that work for you?